# Extreme long build time on teamcity

Tags: .net, wpf, sonarqube, teamcity, roslyn

i'm using teamcity for continuous delivery. We at project decided to use also SonarQube for static code analysis. When i configured it and stared using it slowed build one solutions takes not 2 minutes but like 40 minutes and its always stucked on Roslyn mainly on WPF build. Is there any possibility to optimize Roslyn? Or do you have any good practices to overcomes this?

Thanks for answers.

Comment: How many rules have you enabled? You have the possibility to exclude some projects (for example by tweaking your project https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Excluding+Artifacts+from+the+Analysis)

Comment: I have enable 406 rules and i think this can be problem because there is posibility that they are duplicated. Can it slow build down?

Comment: The more rules the slower the build but that's the default behavior of any roslyn-based analyzer. Without knowing a bit more your application (how many projects, how many files, what's the length of files...) it is a bit tricky to give a lot more advice. What I could recommend is to build with a subset of rules and ti have a nightly (for example) build with more rules enabled.

Comment: Ok so its still slow. Application have 10 projects 2571 files and 475k lines of code.